# Race Condition Analysers for .NET

Tags: .net, static-analysis, race-condition

I've seen there are some race condition analysis tools for C++, C and Java. Anyone know of any static analysis tools that do the same for .NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't ever used this tool, but it looks like TypeMock has a tool called Racer that can handle this. Roy Osherove blogged about it [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2008/09/04/finding-deadlocks-with-readerwriterlock-and-typemock-racer.aspx). Another post with a better preview is [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2008/07/08/a-sneak-preview-of-typemock-racer.aspx).